# Storing & Retrieving UTF-8 & ISO-8859-1(Latin) characters in play framework

Tags: java, playframework

I have an application in Play framework where the user can type/paste any characters (utf-8 or latin or etc...) and submits the data to the server.

Server accepts the request and stores data in Couchbase.

The problem is when I retrieve the data some of the latin characters were daggled (not correctly displaying as they were stored).

Comment: Could you explain the way you're retrieving data? The data saved into Couchbase is correct and compliant which the one being inserted?

Comment: thanks for the reply. The problem with my NodeJS app which was sending response in wrong format.